# Tables and Horizontal Scrolling - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently writing an app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. One of the functions of my app is to pull data from a website and append it onto the page. However, part of the data includes a table which gets cut off on my Android (the table is too wide to fit). The solution would be to implement a horizontal scroll bar, but I am having trouble doing such.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
This is what it looks like on [mobile.](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/9661/screenshot1fl.png)
This is what it looks like on [my desktop](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/810/screenshot2ix.png)

Anyway to scroll to the right (x)?

**EDIT 2:**
It's not my HTML I am formatting. I am basically taking the HTML from a successful ajax GET call and dumping it onto the page

```
$('#insert').html(raw_output);
```

Unfortunately, the HTML/CSS of the table is not very good. I could rewrite most of it using jQuery .css, but the quicker and functional solution would just be to add a horiz-scrolbar allowing me to increase spacing on the table.

Comment: Post your code you are having a problem with and tell us what the problem is specifically. Exception or something does not show?

Comment: Edited with images. I've tried overflow: scroll among other things, to no avail. I'm wondering it the issue is jquery.mobile.css and the data-role page

Comment: When you use overflow, did you set width of the element? I still think we can help you better with your code. Could you post your code (html)?

Comment: And as for screen design, do you really think it's necessary to include all columns of desktop in mobile? You can hide some of the column and column content as they don't look good in table view of mobile anyway.

Comment: Yes, I set the width to device-width. I'm not sure if scrollbars are supported in webkit. Thank you for your help thus far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your images, I don't recommend horizontal scroll for your table because the screen looks bad and unprofessional already. Display all of the details of a course in a separate page. For example, course number, time, probably instructor (maybe all in a column) and button would look better. Touching/clicking a row (or a button) would lead to its details.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the table into a div, and set the css of the div to "overflow: auto" or "overflow: scroll". You can change "overflow" to "overflow-x" or "overflow-y" if you only want it to scroll in one direction. "Scroll" will show a disabled scrollbar even if there's no overflow; "auto" will not show anything if there's no overflow, but will show a scrollbar once there is.

Comment: style="overflow: scroll" works perfectly on my desktop browser, but it's not working on mobile webkit (no scrollbar appears nor can you scroll).

Comment: Hmm, I've never actually programmed for mobile before... I Googled a bit and found some articles on ScrollView or the "android:scrollbars" property; have you tried either of those?

Comment: but want about in iOS browsers that didnt show overflow, overflow-x, overflow-y....

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following 
http://jsfiddle.net/9zuxH/21/

Thanks Phill Pafford